# Error code in C

Tags: c, gcc, unistd.h

I am having error with my code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        int i, status;
        pid_t child;
        child=fork();
        if(child == 0){
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            printf("\tChild PID = %d\n", getpid());
            printf("\tChild PPID = %d\n", getppid());
            sleep(1);
        }
        exit(0);
        }
        else{
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            printf("Parent PID = %d\n", getpid());
            printf("Parent PPID = %d\n", getppid());
        }
        }
        waitpid(child, &status, 0);
        return 0;
}
```

I code in GCC(Unix) , and get the following error :

> test.c:27:1: error: expected identifier '(' before '}' token

Can someone suggest me any help? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your example code isn't even 31 lines long, so hard to have an error on line 31 of it.

Comment: exactly: works for me... check if you have some junk after these 27 lines.

Comment: Please provide test.c verbatim.

Comment: Seems to work on LWS after including `<sys/wait.h>`. http://liveworkspace.org/code/4a51ef7203ae4c0ecf66823859bdf7a7

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Maybe the error is about the waitpid identifier.

Comment: @akisuihkonen no junk after that line.

Comment: Which platform this occurs on?

Comment: Why is it so hard to tell us which line is line 31?

Comment: @jens maybe line 27, it is just matter of newline on my code

Comment: For the love of god, don't post FAKE code.

Comment: Not FAKE. The OpenSuse is in my vmware. which is the source code CAN NOT BE COPY/PASTE into my browser.

Comment: Yes, it's fake. You typed it in and the syntax error is gone. How on earth shall we help you? By all means, ftp or scp the file from your VM to something real. Everything else is a waste of time for you and us.

Answer (score 2):

The man page for `waitpid()` states:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Anyway, the error might due to the usage of `pid_t` which is defined in `sys/types.h`.

Using `-Wall` to turn on all compiler warnings would have pointed one to the missing prototype of `waitpid()`.

**Update**: This assumes Linux.

Comment: What man page? Some don't mention `sys/types.h`.

Comment: i try gcc -Wall test.c 
and the output are:
test.c: in function 'main':
test.c:8:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'fork'

Comment: @VladLazarenko: `This page is part of release 3.27 of the Linux man-pages project.  A description of the project, and information about reporting bugs, can be found at http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/.` Please excuse assuming the OP refers to Linux.

Comment: You might like to check your local man-pages for `fork()` or scan the appropriate header files for which declares it and the other functions (`waitpid()`, `sleep()`) you are using and trhen `#include` such file(s) into your sources. @adadeh

Comment: @alk searching manually for the headers isnt it? Ok